# AWK use value of field in regex

Tags: regex, awk

I'm trying to find a string pattern composed of the word CONCLUSION followed by the value of field $2 and field $3 from the same record in field $5.

For example, `my_file.txt` is separated by "|":

```
1|substance1|substance2|red|CONCLUSIONS: the effect of SUBSTANCE1 and SUBSTANCE2 in humans...|
2|substance3|substance4|red|Conclusions: Substance4 is not harmful...|
3|substance5|substance6|red|Substance5 interacts with substance6...|
```

So in this example I only want the first record to be printed because it has the word "CONCLUSIONS" followed by `substance1` followed by `substance2`.

This is what I'm trying but it's not working:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="|";IGNORECASE=1}{if ($5 ~ /CONCLUSIONS.*$2.*$3/) {print $0}}' my_file.txt
```

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="|";IGNORECASE=1} $5 ~ "conclusions.*" $2 ".*" $3' my_file.txt
1|substance1|substance2|red|CONCLUSIONS: the effect of SUBSTANCE1 and SUBSTANCE2 in humans...|
```

#### How It Works

- `BEGIN{FS="|";IGNORECASE=1}`

  This part is unchanged from the code in the question.
- `$5 ~ "conclusions.*" $2 ".*" $3`

  This is a condition: it is true if `$5` matches a regex composed of four strings concatenated together:  `"conclusions.*"`, and `$2`, and `".*"`, and `$3`.

  We have specified no action for this condition.  Consequently, if the condition is true, `awk` performs the default action which is to print the line.

#### Simpler Examples

Consider:

```
$ echo "aa aa" | awk '$2 ~ /$1/'
```

This line prints nothing because `awk` does not substitute in for variables inside a regex.

Observe that no match is found here either:

```
$ echo '$1' | awk '$0 ~ /$1/'
```

There is no match here because, inside a regex,`$` matches only at the end of a line.  So, `/$1/` would only match the end of a line followed by a `1`.  If we want to get a match here, we need to escape the dollar sign:

```
$ echo '$1' | awk '$0 ~ /\$1/'
$1
```

To get a regex that uses awk variables, we can, as is the basis for this answer, do the following:

```
$ echo "aa aa" | awk '$2 ~ $1'
aa aa
```

This does successfully yield a match.

#### A Further Improvement

As Ed Morton suggests in the comments, it might be important to insist that the substances match only on whole words.  In that case, we can use `\\<...\\>` to limit substance matches to whole words.  Thus:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="|";IGNORECASE=1} $5 ~ "conclusions.*\\<" $2 "\\>.*\\<" $3 "\\>"' my_file.txt
```

In this way, `substance1` will not match `substance10`.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this version works while the OP's version did not because an expression between slashes is a [regexp constant](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp-Usage.html#Regexp-Usage) and therefore the content of `$2` and `$3` was not substituted in and the comparison was against a literal `$2` and `$3`, which did not succeed.

Comment: @Simon Correct.  And, I just added a section to the answer expanding on that.

Comment: I would have expected the desired condition to be more like `$5~"\\<conclusions\\>" && $5~"\\<"$2"\\>" && $5~"\\<"$3"\\"'` so it wouldn't matter if the order was substance1 then substance2 or vice-versa and it wouldn't falsely match when $3="substance1" and $5 contains "substance17".

Comment: @EdMorton Excellent suggestion on the whole word matches!  As for substance order the OP's problem statement, as I read it, asked for that specific order.  His sample code was consistent with that.   If he meant otherwise, then your code is the way to go.